# How to decorate mongo documents before sorting?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

An example would be, I have a collection of Users. Some users have an `age` field and some don't, i.e.:

```
userA: {
    age: 10
}
```

```
userB: {
    age: null
}
```

```
userC: {
    age: 20
}
```

I'd like to decorate all users without an `age` value to `{age: 15}` and then sort by `age`. So the desired outcome of this find and sort would be: `[userA, userB, userC]`. Is there way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$ifNull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) operator to set default value:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            age: { $ifNull: [ "$age", 15 ] }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: { age: 1 }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/m4L0WFA67Fu)